# Why doesn't this disappear after hovering?

Tags: html, css

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mEVHp/)

#### HTML

```
<p>im a duck</p>
```

#### CSS

```
p:hover {
    display:none;
}
```

Shouldn't it disappear after hovering?

Comment: I think you're basically telling it not to do anything since there isn't anything to show.

Comment: Yes...but it depends on what else is going on.

Comment: It does, but very quickly! :D http://jsfiddle.net/8xKeX/ - besides, `<p>` and text strings aren't a good target for something like this

Comment: It is. Fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/vzzr5/](http://jsfiddle.net/vzzr5/)

Comment: It does and it doesn't. You might see the text flashing as you move your mouse over it. Effectively if it is not displayed then it can't be hovered over, so the CSS condition is not being met.

Comment: When it disappears, the hover effect finishes, so it's restored to its previous state (visible). So it appears again.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question? It's a good one in my opinion. I didn't know this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple alternative would be to do something like this:

```
p:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

However, that will only work while the hovering it happening. It's won't hide the element once hovering has ceased.

Comment: Although you didn't provide an answer about why that was happening this was the best solution.Thanks to you and to other people who answered, all appreciated.

Comment: `Although you didn't provide an answer about why that was happening` ... Hehe, I figured others had done it already, so there was not point repeating it. :-)

Answer (score 13):

It does disappear.

However, after it disappears, it's no longer hovered, so it re-appears.

Each time you move the mouse, the cycle repeats; if you move the mouse over it, you'll see it flickering.

The exact behavior depends on the browser; in particular, Chrome only recalculates hover states on mouse events.

Comment: It would appear that the asker is trying to use hover as an event that fires once and sets a property. Hover is a state more than it is an event.

Comment: @Gray I removed my comment, the answer of Gal V fixes it as well

Comment: @Gray: Not just `:hover`, but all of CSS.

Answer (score 3):

this will make more sense to you.

html:

```
<div class="cont"><p>foo</p></div>
```

css:

```
.cont{width:100%;height:30px;}
.cont p{}
.cont:hover p{display:none}
```

hope that helped.

Answer (score 2):

With `display: none` you're completely removing the element from visibility, including height and width. So when you hover it, you completely remove it thus resulting in not hovering, then it reappears. It's a pretty interesting cycle.

You may want to look into `visbility` or trying to set it within a container that doesn't get hidden so you have some sort of hoverable object at all times.

Answer (score 1):

It will be working, but note that once the element goes `display: none`, you can't hover it anymore, because there's nothing to display. So it goes unhovered, which then allows the rule to apply again, so essentially you're flickering between hovered and un-hovered VERY quickly, essentially making it look like nothing's happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
display:none
```

Will hide the element on hover, thus the element is no longer hovered over, so it reappears.

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Will set the element to invisible, however under the visibility state the element is no longer listening to the `hover` event and so will reappear, similar to `display:none`

Technically, you could do this on hover to get the desired effect

```
opacity:0;
```

and the element will remain hidden whilst you are hovering over it. This is due to the element still listening for events as opacity doesn't affect this.

Here's a fiddle comparing the 3

http://jsfiddle.net/mEVHp/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do this job

```
$('p').hover(function(){
 $(this).hide();
});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWxzq/1/) for more info.